# mysql select any one field out of two with respect to the value of a third field

Tags: mysql

I want to select either price or sale_price with respect to the value in the field named nosale. where price, sale_price and nosale are fields of a product table.

The nosale field will be either true or false. According to that i want either the value of price or sale_price and not both.

How to form a single query to fetch like i mentioned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT IF(nosale = 1, price, sale_price) AS `something` FROM table ...
```

or

```
SELECT CASE WHEN nosale = 1 THEN price ELSE sale_price END AS `something` FROM table ...
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html

Comment: yes it works. i forgot to mention that i need to use a date range for nosale. if(nosale =1 && fromdate<=today && today>=todate)then i want the second field else i want the first field. is it possible to nest if condition inside  query?

Comment: Yes, write it like you did in the comment, though it is more common to use `AND` instead of `&&` in MySQL queries. The condition is an expression which can have as many AND/OR'd parts as you need.

Comment: i got it. i just used it like i said and i saw your reply. thank you.