# SQL: How do I select one of two fields, depending on a third field

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to export data from an existing TABLE. Till recently I used -

```
SELECT item_ID, item_Info, ...moreFields... FROM tableName WHERE myCondition=0
```

Now, they changed the TABLE structure, and added new field "item_Info2"

When they fill in the TABLE:

- if "item_Type" is 1 or 2 or 3 or 4, then "item_Info" is relevant
- if "item_Type" is 5, then "item_Info" is empty, and I need "item_Info2" as my query result, instead of "item_Info"

What is the corresponding SELECT command?

[similiar question: [mysql select any one field out of two with respect to the value of a third field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815136/mysql-select-any-one-field-out-of-two-with-respect-to-the-value-of-a-third-field)

**but** from this example I cannot see the syntax for selecting moreFields ]

Thanks,

Atara.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can treat the `CASE` statement as any other column name, separate it from the other columns with a comma, etc. What happens in the `CASE` should be considered a single column name, in your case you need commas before and after it.

```
SELECT item_ID, CASE WHEN item_Type = 5 THEN item_info ELSE item_info2 END, field_name, another_field_name ...moreFields... FROM tableName WHERE myCondition=0
```

you could also use an alias to be easier to get the result from the query:

```
SELECT item_ID, CASE WHEN item_Type = 5 THEN item_info ELSE item_info2 END AS 'item_info', field_name, another_field_name ...moreFields... FROM tableName WHERE myCondition=0
```

Answer (score 3):

To edit the reply on the other question:

```
SELECT 
  item_id, item_otherproperty,
  CASE WHEN item_Type= 5
   THEN item_Info2
   ELSE item_Info
  END AS `info` FROM table ...
```

Comment: Upvoted this answer because the vertical alignment makes the code more understandable than the horizontal alignment of the accepted answer.